# cakephp 3.8 store ajax data in database

Tags: ajax, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to store ajax data into the database in cakephp 3.8.

The data looks like:

[image]

The data stands for 2 checked checkboxes, with hidden inputs.

I am using the following ajax code:

```js
var formData = menuItem;

var formUrl = $('#nav-menu-meta').attr('action');

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: formUrl,
    data: formData,
    success: function(response,textStatus,xhr) {
        console.log('test ', response);

    },
    error: function(xhr,textStatus,error) {
        console.error(textStatus, error);
    }
});
```

```
public function addmenuitems() {
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->response->disableCache();
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $menuitemTable = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('menuitems');
        $menuitems = $menuitemTable->newEntities($this->request->getData());

        foreach ($menuitems as $menuitem) {
            if ($menuitemTable->save($menuitem)) {
                $response = $this->response->withType('application/json')
                    ->withStringBody(json_encode($menuitem));
                return $response;
            }else{
                $message = 'Error';
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

The data is not saved at all, so what am I missing?

I added the debug data array from the getData() function to show what the array contain:

```
/src/Controller/Admin/Web/MenusController.php (line 109)
[
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\MenuItem) {

        'menu_item_object_id' => (int) 2,
        'menu_item_title' => 'Home',
        'menu_item_slug' => 'home',
        'menu_item_parent_id' => (int) 0,
        'menu_item_target' => false,
        'menu_item_position' => (int) 0,
        '[new]' => true,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true,
            'id' => false,
            'menu-item-object_id' => true,
            'menu-item-parent_id' => true,
            'menu-item-position' => true,
            'lft' => true,
            'rght' => true,
            'menu-item-title' => true,
            'menu-item-slug' => true,
            'menu-item-target' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [
            'menu_item_object_id' => true,
            'menu_item_title' => true,
            'menu_item_slug' => true,
            'menu_item_parent_id' => true,
            'menu_item_target' => true,
            'menu_item_position' => true
        ],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[hasErrors]' => false,
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'menuitems'

    },
    (int) 1 => object(App\Model\Entity\MenuItem) {

        'menu_item_object_id' => (int) 3,
        'menu_item_title' => 'Nieuw',
        'menu_item_slug' => 'nieuw',
        'menu_item_parent_id' => (int) 0,
        'menu_item_target' => false,
        'menu_item_position' => (int) 0,
        '[new]' => true,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true,
            'id' => false,
            'menu-item-object_id' => true,
            'menu-item-parent_id' => true,
            'menu-item-position' => true,
            'lft' => true,
            'rght' => true,
            'menu-item-title' => true,
            'menu-item-slug' => true,
            'menu-item-target' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [
            'menu_item_object_id' => true,
            'menu_item_title' => true,
            'menu_item_slug' => true,
            'menu_item_parent_id' => true,
            'menu_item_target' => true,
            'menu_item_position' => true
        ],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[hasErrors]' => false,
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'menuitems'

    }
]
```

Comment: `$menuitems` is a single entity. Trying to iterate over it will not give you things that can be saved.

Comment: I already tried it without the line before the foreach and gave me the same results.

Comment: I updated my code, removed the line, which was not needed. But the results are still the same, nothing stored in the database.

Comment: You're still trying to iterate over an entity, not an array of entities. What do `debug($menuitems)` and `debug($menuitem)` show you? That might be instructive in seeing where your problem lies.

Comment: @GregSchmidt thanks, I looked at cakephp: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records but it only saves the first array, while it should save all, according to the documentation. I updated the code above.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, I also added the debug data

Comment: Okay, you're now correctly dealing with an array of entities. Excellent! But then you loop through, and if the first one saves correctly, you return from the function. Hence why only one is saved. Assuming you're using at least version 3.2.8 of Cake, you want to drop the `foreach` loop entirely and use [`saveMany`](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-multiple-entities) there, not `save`.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, yes that did it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @GregSchmidt, one tiny question. Is it possible to get the id of each entity after adding it to the database using saveMany? This something I want to get and returned.

Comment: They should all be in the entities, I believe. They certainly are after `save`, so I expect `saveMany` would behave the same.

Comment: @GregSchmidt. Thanks, I checked: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#aftersave. And it works for debug, but other then that, there is not much documentation. Can it be used in a controller to the ids of every entity in an array and return that?

Comment: I meant that, after the `saveMany` call returns, the entities in your array should have been modified so that they all include the ids. So, something like `collection($menuitems)->extract('id')->toArray()` might work well for you.